# PrimeNG - FullCalendar: cannot access fullCalendar methods

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, primeng, fullcalendar-4

I have an Angular 7 app in which I use `PrimeNG` and FullCalendar 4 to display and manage a day schedule.
To delete an Event I added a custom delete Icon to the rendered events and bound its onClick event to my onEventDeleteClicked function.

As per `PrimeNG` documentation, I added a `ViewChild` for the Calendar to access its methods (code below).
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fullcalendar

*component.ts ViewChild and onEventDeleteClicked*

```js
@ViewChild('daySchedule') fc: FullCalendar;

public onEventDeleteClicked(event: Event): void {
    // Delete selected Event
    const calendar = this.fc.getCalendar();
    console.log(event);
}
```

*component.html*

```html
<div class="calendar-container">
    <p-fullCalendar #daySchedule [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
</div>
```

However when I try to call `"const calendar = this.fc.getCalendar();"` in the method I get the `Error: "Cannot get getCalendar of undefined"`

I have checked within fullCalendars own callbacks like eventRender and the Angular lifecycle hook `AfterViewInit`. In both of them, FC is defined and I am able to access `getCalendar()` but it seems outside of this FC is undefined when accessed from any of my own functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging and testing I found that the event listener I added to the icon via:

```
element.addEventListener('click', this.onEventDropped, false);
```

was the issue. Replacing that with Angulars Renderer2 fixed the issue for me.

```
this.renderer.listen(element, 'click', (dropEvent: any) => {
          this.onEventDropped(dropEvent);
        });
```

Comment: Where should I need to replace let me know, please?
I have the same issue but I can't use this solution